# Уведомление о новом письме в Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

Имеется плагин в outlook для уведомления и новом письме в дополнительном ящике. Но проблема в том что когда приходит новое письмо и Outlook находится в свёрнутом состоянии то уведомлении не отображается

Код ниже:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    const string recipientName = "mymail@mydomain.com";

    var recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
    recip.Resolve();

    if (!recip.Resolved) return;
    var inboxFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    inboxFolder.Items.ItemAdd += InboxFolderItemAdded;

}

private static void InboxFolderItemAdded(object item) {
    if (item is Outlook.MailItem) {
        MessageBox.Show("Новое сообщение", "new message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Прошу оказать помощь в решении проблемы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последуйте [официальному примеру](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): сделайте `Items` полем. Проблема в том, что подписка действует до тех пор, пока объект жив. А после выхода из метода `ThisAddIn_Startup()` переменная `inboxFolder` и, соответственно, поле `Items` становится доступным для сборки мусора. Также имейте в виду, что согласно [документации на это событие](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx), оно не триггерится, если приходит сразу много сообщений (насколько много -- не уточняется :)).

```
Outlook.Items _items;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    const string recipientName = "mymail@mydomain.com";

    var recip = ns.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
    recip.Resolve();

    if (!recip.Resolved) return;
    var inboxFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    _items = inboxFolder.Items;
    _items.ItemAdd += InboxFolderItemAdded;

}

private static void InboxFolderItemAdded(object item) {
    if (item is Outlook.MailItem) {
        MessageBox.Show("Новое сообщение", "new message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, добрый человек. Дай бог тебе здоровья)

Comment: @Павел не за что :). Рад, что помогло.